# How to develop or use the maps application search dialog in android

Tags: android, dialog, maps, autosuggest

I have been looking for information about how to build a search dialog with suggestions of google maps addresses but I could not find a way. ¿Is any way of calling via INTENT to the maps app only for searching an address (with suggestions) and handle the result address in my own MapActivity? ¿Or how can I develop it? For developing it my problem is how to make the suggestions, because I suppose that the suggestions have to come from the geocoder, or not?
And the last question, ¿why the addresses taken from the geocoder are different from the ones suggested in google maps app while typing?

Thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

There's a list of [available intents here](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html).

I believe you can use Intent data like this to perform a search:

```
geo:0,0?q=search_terms
```

Comment: But what I want is to load the search dialog of maps app, and receive the response with the address typed by the user in my activity, in order to paint a marker in my map.